# Найти ошибку в решении задачи "Семипроцентный барьер"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дана задача. В Государственную Думу Федерального Собрания Российской Федерации выборы производятся по партийным спискам. Каждый избиратель указывает одну партию, за которую он отдает свой голос. В Государственную Думу попадают партии, которые набрали не менее 7% от числа голосов избирателей.
Дан список партий и список голосов избирателей. Выведите список партий, которые попадут в Государственную Думу.

Формат ввода
В первой строке входного файла написано слово PARTIES:. Далее идет список партий, участвующих в выборах.
Затем идет строка, содержащая слово VOTES:. За ним идут названия партий, за которые проголосовали избиратели, по одному названию в строке. Названия могут быть только строками из первого списка.

Формат вывода
Программа должна вывести названия партий, получивших не менее 7% от числа голосов в том порядке, в котором они следуют в первом списке.

Тест 1

Входные данные:

```
PARTIES:
Party one
Party two
Party three
VOTES:
Party one
Party one
Party three
Party one
Party one
Party three
Party two
Party one
Party three
Party three
Party one
Party one
Party three
Party three
Party one
```

Вывод программы:

```
Party one
Party three
```

Тест 2
Входные данные:

```
PARTIES:
Party one
VOTES:
Party one
Party one
Party one
Party one
Party one
Party one
Party one
```

Вывод программы:

```
Party one
```

Тест 3
Входные данные:

```
PARTIES:
The first party
The best party
VOTES:
The best party
The best party
The best party
The best party
The best party
The best party
The best party
The first party
The best party
The best party
The best party
The best party
The best party
The best party
```

Вывод программы:

```
The first party
The best party
```

Разработанный и представленный ниже код выдаёт ошибку на тесте 4, данных которого нет. Собственные тесты дают верный результат. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку.

```
fin = open("input.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
fout = open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")
reader = fin.readlines()
parties = []
vote = []
votes = 0
for i in reader:
    if i == 'VOTES:\n':
        votes = 1
    if votes == 0:
        parties.append(i)
    else:
        vote.append(i)
parties.pop(0)
vote.pop(0)
parties = [line.rstrip() for line in parties]
vote = [line.rstrip() for line in vote]
partwin = [0] * len(parties)
total = 0
for j in range(len(parties)):
    for k in range(len(vote)):
        if parties[j] == vote[k]:
            partwin[j] += 1
            total += 1
total *= 0.07
for m in range(len(partwin)):
    if partwin[m] >= total:
        print(parties[m], file=fout)
fout.close()
```

Comment: Ладно, данных Теста 4 нет, но Код ошибки сообщить-то хотя бы можно?    И еще непонятно, как собственные тесты на данных которых нет, могут давать верный результат?

Comment: В тексте выше приведены 3 теста, данные которых есть. Их программа проходит. Придуманные самостоятельно тесты выкладывать не стал, они по логике похожи на первые три. Тестирующая система выдаёт неинформативную ошибку, а именно: "Test 4
Wrong answer."

Comment: если у вас есть ограничения (такие как нельзя использовать словари, import-ы), то следует это явно прямо в вопросе упоминать.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
with open("input.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as fin:
    with open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf8") as fout:
        parties = []
        votes = {}
        count = 0
        get_parties = False
        get_votes = False
        for line in fin:
            if 'PARTIES:' in line:
                get_parties = True
                get_votes = False
                continue
            if 'VOTES:' in line:
                get_votes = True
                get_parties = False
                continue
            if get_parties:
                parties.append(line)
                votes[line] = 0
                continue
            if get_votes:
                votes[line] += 1
                count += 1
        for party in parties:
            if votes[party] / count * 100 >= 7:
                fout.write(party)
```

Вариант без словаря. `votes` - список с количеством голосов, индексы соответствуют партиям из `parties`:

```
with open("input.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as fin:
    with open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf8") as fout:
        parties = []
        votes = []
        count = 0
        get_parties = False
        get_votes = False
        for line in fin:
            if line.find('PARTIES:') != -1:
                get_parties = True
                get_votes = False
                continue
            if line.find('VOTES:') != -1:
                get_votes = True
                get_parties = False
                continue
            if get_parties:
                parties.append(line)
                votes.append(0)
                continue
            if get_votes:
                votes[parties.index(line)] += 1
                count += 1
        for index, party in enumerate(parties):
            if votes[index] / count * 100 >= 7:
                fout.write(party)
```

Comment: Этот код, как и код ниже - проходит. Но оба используют конструкции, которых мы формально не проходили и хочется не подогнать решение под ответ, а разобраться.

Comment: from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

    class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
        pass

    oc = OrderedCounter(l for l in map(str.rstrip, open('input.txt'))
                    if l not in ('PARTIES:', 'VOTES:'))
    votes = sum(oc.values()) - len(oc)
    print('\n'.join(str(p) for p in oc if (oc[p] - 1) / votes >= 0.07))

Comment: что конкретно не проходили?

Comment: или наоборот, что можно использовать?

Comment: словари ещё не проходили, если из примера выше. Множества тоже ещё не проходили. Можно использовать строки и их методы, списки, циклы, условия.

Comment: добавил вариант без словаря и использовал методы строк

Comment: Отлично! Код понятен, решение системой также принято! А шансов понять что с моим кодом не так - нет? )

Comment: Код выглядит рабочим,посмотреть бы на тест, который не проходит

Answer (score 1):

Код в вопросе, должен работать, если ввод содержит `'VOTES:\n'`. Условие говорит: *"Затем идет строка, содержащая слово VOTES:"* что можно интерпретировать, что в строке могут быть и другие символы:

```
PARTIES:
Party one
VOTES: something
Party one
```

[Ваш код завершается с ошибкой на этом вводе](https://ideone.com/87B7Ml).

Вариант для сравнения: чтобы напечатать какие партии прошли в приведённом порядке:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile

def read_parties(lines):
    next(lines) # skip PARTIES header
    return takewhile(lambda s: 'VOTES:' not in s, lines)

def get_elected_parties(parties, threshold=0.07):
    votes = Counter(parties)
    min_nvotes = threshold * sum(votes.values())  
    return {party for party, nvotes in votes.items() if nvotes >= min_nvotes}

lines = map(str.strip,  fileinput.input())
parties = list(read_parties(lines))
elected_parties = get_elected_parties(lines)
for party in parties:
    if party in elected_parties:
        print(party)
```

Пример:

```
$ ./print-elected-parties test1
```

#### [Результат](https://ideone.com/5G4syD)

```
Party one
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython_stdlib.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile

def read_parties(lines):
    next(lines) # skip PARTIES header
    return takewhile(lambda s: 'VOTES:' not in s, lines)
                
def get_elected_parties(parties, threshold=0.07):
    votes = Counter()
    for party in parties:
        votes[party] += 1
    min_nvotes = threshold * sum(votes.values())  
    return {party for party, nvotes in votes.items() if nvotes >= min_nvotes}


# try your own input    
from browser import document, html
@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event):
    lines = map(str.strip,  document['content'].value.splitlines())
    parties = list(read_parties(lines))
    elected_parties = get_elected_parties(lines)
    div = document['output']
    div.clear()
    for party in parties:
        if party in elected_parties:
            div <= html.P(party)
</script>
<textarea id="content" rows=10 cols=30>
PARTIES:
Party one
Party two
Party three
VOTES:
Party one
Party one
Party three
Party one
Party one
Party three
Party two
Party one
Party three
Party three
Party one
Party one
Party three
Party three
Party one
</textarea><button id="mybutton">Запустить</button><div id="output"></div></body>
```